# dgl from_networkx function running out of memory

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dgl

I am creating a graph through networkx and then converting it to a dgl graph with the function [from_networkx](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.6.x/generated/dgl.from_networkx.html). If I do it with small graphs (around 2k nodes and edges) it works but when I tried with bigger graphs (100k nodes and edges) it always crash the kernel due to memory.
Is it possible to convert a large networkx graph to dgl? or it only works for small ones?

Comment: Which device did you used? GPU or CPU? If GPU have you tried it on CPU?

Comment: Yes, I tried on both, and it always crash the RAM.

Comment: I guess your CPU will have more RAM. Since the note in the linked docs say that this function is not optimal, have you tried the manual creation based on node-tensors? If you are not bound with the library I also recommend checking PytorchGeometric.

Comment: Yes, I could resolve it by manual creation, but it would be better to use netwokx as it is a more easy way.